# Finding all the dates that event occures

Tags: java

I am given a start date of an event which it's format is of form `yyyy_mm_dd`(Of String form) and a non-negative integer n which denotes the number of repetitions of the event.For example if the start date is 2020_3_12 and I have 3 repetitions then the event will be hold on days `2020_3_12` and `2020_3_19` and `2020_3_26` and `2020_4_3` (Weekly repeat).I am continiously given a date and I have to determine wheter the date has a event of that type or not also the repetition may change during the program run.I can just store the valid dates in an array or set and search for them but the problem is that finding all the dates has a lot of case work(When we have to change the month or year when adding 7 days)Is there a nice way to escape from these edge cases?(I am looking for a java solution.Thanks in advance).Also is there a nicer way to handle this so that I can avoid reconstructing the array each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the described result:

```
String input = "2020_3_12";
int repeat = 3;

LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_M_dd"));

List<LocalDate> eventDates = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++){
    eventDates.add(start.plusDays(7 * i));
}
System.out.println(eventDates);
```

With streams you can also write the upper example a little more compactly

```
List<LocalDate> eventDates2 =  IntStream.rangeClosed(0, repeat)
                                        .mapToObj(i -> start.plusDays(i * 7))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(eventDates2);
```

You could also work directly with LocalDate in the for loop instead of ints

```
List<LocalDate> eventDates3 = new ArrayList<>();
for(LocalDate date = start; date.isBefore(start.plusDays(repeat*7 +1)); date = date.plusDays(7)){
    eventDates3.add(date);
}

System.out.println(eventDates3);
```

Comment: I need the month to be always two digits is there any method to do this with a little modification especially for the first one since I am very interested in it.

Comment: Not sure if I get it right. If you mean the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_M_dd")` just adjust it according to your input. If your input is like `2020_3_12` use `"yyyy_M_dd"` or if you have input like  `2020_03_12` then use `"yyyy_MM_dd"`

Comment: Good answer. A little detail, there’s no need to do your own multiplication by 7 since `LocalDate` has got a `plusWeeks` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        //Declaration
        String pattern = "yyyy_MM_dd";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        int n = 3;
        int step = 2;
        
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("2021_03_19", formatter);
        
        //It is a incrementing count of days where day 0 is 1970-01-01
        long epochDay = startDate.toEpochDay();
        
        //Test
        LocalDate testDate = startDate;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("testDate: " + testDate);
            long offset = testDate.toEpochDay() - epochDay;
            boolean isValid = offset % step == 0 && offset / step < n;
            System.out.println("isValid:  " + isValid);
            testDate = testDate.plusDays(1);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
testDate: 2021-03-19
isValid:  true

testDate: 2021-03-20
isValid:  false

testDate: 2021-03-21
isValid:  true

testDate: 2021-03-22
isValid:  false

testDate: 2021-03-23
isValid:  true

testDate: 2021-03-24
isValid:  false

testDate: 2021-03-25
isValid:  false

testDate: 2021-03-26
isValid:  false

testDate: 2021-03-27
isValid:  false

testDate: 2021-03-28
isValid:  false
```

Comment: While probably correct I believe that your code is more complicated than necessary.